# setting up contiki on TI CC1310

Tags: embedded, iot

I got a prototype TI CC1310 board. I searched online to see if there are any IoT examples or demos or even a setup guide in setting up contiki stack on the device.
Can anyone help me in setting up the the CC1310 board. I am using a SmartRF06 board.

Comment: Asking for off-site resources is off-topic for Stack Overflow. That being said, one big warning here: TI in general is notorious for publishing completely awful, beginner-mistake-level source code in their application notes. Out of personal experience, I can say that this is _especially_ true for their sub-GHz Chipcon radio. Be wary of any "offical" source code coming from TI.

Comment: @Lundin, okay  I have updated the question , thanks. Its just that I am stuck and is not having much clue on what to do.

Answer (score 0):

Here's [a link](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Cc26xx_sw_examples) that you can find some examples of how to set up and program the Contiki OS on SmartRF06+CC1310EM.

Comment: sharing link is not proper answer, help him by some working code

Comment: The question is about setup the environment, not about code examples.